# "Permission denied" error with Laravel "new" command, with Homestead on Vagrant

Tags: php, laravel, ubuntu, vagrant, homestead

I am using Vagrant and Laravel Homestead with Ubuntu 14.

Here is the error I am getting when I run `laravel new <project>`:

```
vagrant@homestead:~/sites$ laravel new chatty
Crafting application...
PHP Warning:  file_put_contents(/home/vagrant/sites/laravel_e4dd1c8bc2e02a3e6897f5728f025b4a.zip): failed to open stream: Permission denied in /home/vagrant/.config/composer/vendor/laravel/installer/src/NewCommand.php on line 120
PHP Stack trace:
PHP   1. {main}() /home/vagrant/.config/composer/vendor/laravel/installer/laravel:0
PHP   2. Symfony\Component\Console\Application->run() /home/vagrant/.config/composer/vendor/laravel/installer/laravel:13
PHP   3. Symfony\Component\Console\Application->doRun() /home/vagrant/.config/composer/vendor/symfony/console/Application.php:123
PHP   4. Symfony\Component\Console\Application->doRunCommand() /home/vagrant/.config/composer/vendor/symfony/console/Application.php:192
PHP   5. Symfony\Component\Console\Command\Command->run() /home/vagrant/.config/composer/vendor/symfony/console/Application.php:844
PHP   6. Laravel\Installer\Console\NewCommand->execute() /home/vagrant/.config/composer/vendor/symfony/console/Command/Command.php:259
PHP   7. Laravel\Installer\Console\NewCommand->download() /home/vagrant/.config/composer/vendor/laravel/installer/src/NewCommand.php:53
PHP   8. file_put_contents() /home/vagrant/.config/composer/vendor/laravel/installer/src/NewCommand.php:120

Warning: file_put_contents(/home/vagrant/sites/laravel_e4dd1c8bc2e02a3e6897f5728f025b4a.zip): failed to open stream: Permission denied in /home/vagrant/.config/composer/vendor/laravel/installer/src/NewCommand.php on line 120

Call Stack:
    0.0001     350512   1. {main}() /home/vagrant/.config/composer/vendor/laravel/installer/laravel:0
    0.0159    1713096   2. Symfony\Component\Console\Application->run() /home/vagrant/.config/composer/vendor/laravel/installer/laravel:13
    0.0186    1928584   3. Symfony\Component\Console\Application->doRun() /home/vagrant/.config/composer/vendor/symfony/console/Application.php:123
    0.0187    1928584   4. Symfony\Component\Console\Application->doRunCommand() /home/vagrant/.config/composer/vendor/symfony/console/Application.php:192
    0.0187    1928584   5. Symfony\Component\Console\Command\Command->run() /home/vagrant/.config/composer/vendor/symfony/console/Application.php:844
    0.0189    1930520   6. Laravel\Installer\Console\NewCommand->execute() /home/vagrant/.config/composer/vendor/symfony/console/Command/Command.php:259
    0.0196    1930672   7. Laravel\Installer\Console\NewCommand->download() /home/vagrant/.config/composer/vendor/laravel/installer/src/NewCommand.php:53
    2.2559    2917832   8. file_put_contents() /home/vagrant/.config/composer/vendor/laravel/installer/src/NewCommand.php:120

PHP Warning:  ZipArchive::extractTo(): Permission denied in /home/vagrant/.config/composer/vendor/laravel/installer/src/NewCommand.php on line 138
PHP Stack trace:
PHP   1. {main}() /home/vagrant/.config/composer/vendor/laravel/installer/laravel:0
PHP   2. Symfony\Component\Console\Application->run() /home/vagrant/.config/composer/vendor/laravel/installer/laravel:13
PHP   3. Symfony\Component\Console\Application->doRun() /home/vagrant/.config/composer/vendor/symfony/console/Application.php:123
PHP   4. Symfony\Component\Console\Application->doRunCommand() /home/vagrant/.config/composer/vendor/symfony/console/Application.php:192
PHP   5. Symfony\Component\Console\Command\Command->run() /home/vagrant/.config/composer/vendor/symfony/console/Application.php:844
PHP   6. Laravel\Installer\Console\NewCommand->execute() /home/vagrant/.config/composer/vendor/symfony/console/Command/Command.php:259
PHP   7. Laravel\Installer\Console\NewCommand->extract() /home/vagrant/.config/composer/vendor/laravel/installer/src/NewCommand.php:54
PHP   8. ZipArchive->extractTo() /home/vagrant/.config/composer/vendor/laravel/installer/src/NewCommand.php:138

Warning: ZipArchive::extractTo(): Permission denied in /home/vagrant/.config/composer/vendor/laravel/installer/src/NewCommand.php on line 138

Call Stack:
    0.0001     350512   1. {main}() /home/vagrant/.config/composer/vendor/laravel/installer/laravel:0
    0.0159    1713096   2. Symfony\Component\Console\Application->run() /home/vagrant/.config/composer/vendor/laravel/installer/laravel:13
    0.0186    1928584   3. Symfony\Component\Console\Application->doRun() /home/vagrant/.config/composer/vendor/symfony/console/Application.php:123
    0.0187    1928584   4. Symfony\Component\Console\Application->doRunCommand() /home/vagrant/.config/composer/vendor/symfony/console/Application.php:192
    0.0187    1928584   5. Symfony\Component\Console\Command\Command->run() /home/vagrant/.config/composer/vendor/symfony/console/Application.php:844
    0.0189    1930520   6. Laravel\Installer\Console\NewCommand->execute() /home/vagrant/.config/composer/vendor/symfony/console/Command/Command.php:259
    2.2601    2736952   7. Laravel\Installer\Console\NewCommand->extract() /home/vagrant/.config/composer/vendor/laravel/installer/src/NewCommand.php:54
    2.2601    2737032   8. ZipArchive->extractTo() /home/vagrant/.config/composer/vendor/laravel/installer/src/NewCommand.php:138

PHP Warning:  ZipArchive::close(): Invalid or uninitialized Zip object in /home/vagrant/.config/composer/vendor/laravel/installer/src/NewCommand.php on line 140
PHP Stack trace:
PHP   1. {main}() /home/vagrant/.config/composer/vendor/laravel/installer/laravel:0
PHP   2. Symfony\Component\Console\Application->run() /home/vagrant/.config/composer/vendor/laravel/installer/laravel:13
PHP   3. Symfony\Component\Console\Application->doRun() /home/vagrant/.config/composer/vendor/symfony/console/Application.php:123
PHP   4. Symfony\Component\Console\Application->doRunCommand() /home/vagrant/.config/composer/vendor/symfony/console/Application.php:192
PHP   5. Symfony\Component\Console\Command\Command->run() /home/vagrant/.config/composer/vendor/symfony/console/Application.php:844
PHP   6. Laravel\Installer\Console\NewCommand->execute() /home/vagrant/.config/composer/vendor/symfony/console/Command/Command.php:259
PHP   7. Laravel\Installer\Console\NewCommand->extract() /home/vagrant/.config/composer/vendor/laravel/installer/src/NewCommand.php:54
PHP   8. ZipArchive->close() /home/vagrant/.config/composer/vendor/laravel/installer/src/NewCommand.php:140

Warning: ZipArchive::close(): Invalid or uninitialized Zip object in /home/vagrant/.config/composer/vendor/laravel/installer/src/NewCommand.php on line 140

Call Stack:
    0.0001     350512   1. {main}() /home/vagrant/.config/composer/vendor/laravel/installer/laravel:0
    0.0159    1713096   2. Symfony\Component\Console\Application->run() /home/vagrant/.config/composer/vendor/laravel/installer/laravel:13
    0.0186    1928584   3. Symfony\Component\Console\Application->doRun() /home/vagrant/.config/composer/vendor/symfony/console/Application.php:123
    0.0187    1928584   4. Symfony\Component\Console\Application->doRunCommand() /home/vagrant/.config/composer/vendor/symfony/console/Application.php:192
    0.0187    1928584   5. Symfony\Component\Console\Command\Command->run() /home/vagrant/.config/composer/vendor/symfony/console/Application.php:844
    0.0189    1930520   6. Laravel\Installer\Console\NewCommand->execute() /home/vagrant/.config/composer/vendor/symfony/console/Command/Command.php:259
    2.2601    2736952   7. Laravel\Installer\Console\NewCommand->extract() /home/vagrant/.config/composer/vendor/laravel/installer/src/NewCommand.php:54
    2.2605    2737032   8. ZipArchive->close() /home/vagrant/.config/composer/vendor/laravel/installer/src/NewCommand.php:140

You are running composer with xdebug enabled. This has a major impact on runtime performance. See https://getcomposer.org/xdebug
Composer could not find a composer.json file in /home/vagrant/sites
To initialize a project, please create a composer.json file as described in the https://getcomposer.org/ "Getting Started" section
Application ready! Build something amazing.
```

When I run `sudo laravel new <project>`, it says

```
sudo: laravel: command not found
```

Also is it the issue of Ubuntu 14 installed in Vagrant instead of Ubuntu 16 ?

**Edit (after kmasteryc comments):**

Thanks, but I tried your `composer create-project laravel/laravel project` too, but now I am getting this error

```
vagrant@homestead:~/sites$ composer create-project laravel/laravel chatty
You are running composer with xdebug enabled. This has a major impact on runtime performance. See https://getcomposer.org/xdebug
Installing laravel/laravel (v5.2.31)


  [ErrorException]            
  mkdir(): Permission denied  


create-project [-s|--stability STABILITY] [--prefer-source] [--prefer-dist] [--repository REPOSITORY] [--repository-url REPOSITORY-URL] [--dev] [--no-dev] [--no-custom-installers] [--no-scripts] [--no-progress] [--no-secure-http] [--keep-vcs] [--no-install] [--ignore-platform-reqs] [--] [<package>] [<directory>] [<version>]
```

Then I ran it with `sudo` and it worked, but it is giving this warning now:

```
Do not run Composer as root/super user! See https://getcomposer.org/root for details
```

So is there any way to run this command without `sudo` as it's not [recommended](https://getcomposer.org/doc/faqs/how-to-install-untrusted-packages-safely.md)?

Moreover this isn't syncing the created project to my local directory and after mapping chatty.dev to " chatty " folder (virtual hosting) then running `vagrant provision`, I am getting this below error

```
harman@manchanda:~/web/Homestead$ vagrant provision
There are errors in the configuration of this machine. Please fix
the following errors and try again:

vm:
* The host path of the shared folder is missing: ~/web/sites/chatty
```

And my code is correct. But still, please see this `homestead.yaml` file code too:

```
---
ip: "192.168.10.10"
memory: 2048
cpus: 1
provider: virtualbox

authorize: ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub

keys:
    - ~/.ssh/id_rsa

folders:
    - map: ~/web/sites/lv
      to: /home/vagrant/sites/lv
    - map: ~/web/sites/v8
      to: /home/vagrant/sites/v8
    - map: ~/web/sites/chatty
      to: /home/vagrant/sites/chatty
sites:
    - map: lv.app
      to: /home/vagrant/sites/lv/public
    - map: v8.app
      to: /home/vagrant/sites/v8/public
    - map: chatty.dev
      to: /home/vagrant/sites/chatty/public    

databases:
    - homestead
    - homestead_v8
    - homestead_chatty
```

**Edit no 2:**

Here is my new `Homestead.yaml` file after kmasteryc requested edit

```
---
ip: "192.168.10.10"
memory: 2048
cpus: 1
provider: virtualbox

authorize: ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub

keys:
    - ~/.ssh/id_rsa

folders:
    - map: ~/web/sites/
      to: /home/vagrant/sites/
    # - map: ~/web/sites/lv
    #   to: /home/vagrant/sites/lv
    # - map: ~/web/sites/v8
    #   to: /home/vagrant/sites/v8
    # - map: ~/web/sites/chatty
    #   to: /home/vagrant/sites/chatty
sites:
    - map: lv.app
      to: /home/vagrant/sites/lv/public
    - map: v8.app
      to: /home/vagrant/sites/v8/public
    # - map: chatty.dev
    #   to: /home/vagrant/sites/chatty/public    

databases:
    - homestead
    - homestead_v8
    # - homestead_chatty
```

Special note: I have currently commented that chatty thing.

That `laravel new` is now working (thanks to  `sudo chmod 777 -R sites` and `sudo chown -R vagrant sites`) but still the problem is persisting with Vagrant not syncing folders.

Comment: Did you install laravel installer with sudo composer?

Comment: nopes i have added laravel by adding vagrant box .... and infact it was working well till today ... i have created 2 other practice projects also in the vagrant box .... but now today i was creating new project and .... boom ... things didnt go according to the plan :(

Comment: Please note that those two projects were created when ubuntu 14 was the latest version in the vagrant box ... now its ubuntu 16 and i still have ubuntu 14 in my latest version....

Comment: You can try "composer create-project laravel/laravel project" instead of "laravel new project"

Comment: @KmasterYC - Thanks but still having an issue ... edited my question... kindly see !

Comment: - Issue 1 - run sudo all the time. Fix: in the web folder run "sudo chmod 777 sites" and "sudo chown vagrant sites"

Comment: With issue "shared folder is missing". I can't see any problem in Homestead.yaml yet

Comment: thanks for solving issue no 1 but still as you know problem persists with that shared folder missing .... please note that `chatty' project hasnt synced up like before to my local directory .... ie... the Vagrant machine has that `chatty` folder whereas my machine doesn't !

Comment: Try this. Map only ~/web/sites/ to /home/vagrant/sites is enough. Delete chatty on both machine. Run provision again and create project like above. I think problem will be fixed

Comment: did the same .... now infact laravel new is also working but still the folders aren't syncing .... but still thanks for your help

Comment: Np. Post your new Homestead.yaml

Comment: Done bro .... i have posted new homestead.yaml file ... {{ Edit no 2 }}

Comment: And your problem now is chatty folder not appear in host machine?

Comment: Yup u got it right ... Not appearing in my host machine ( my Ubuntu lappy ) ..... and appearing in vagrant machine ( Virtual)